# fill method not working in python with pygame module

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using the `fill` method to fill my black screen with white, but it doesn't work; it gives me a black screen. Here is my code :

```
import pygame

class Bouncer(object):

    display_width = 600
    display_height = 400
    color_white = (255, 255, 255)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    game_exit = False

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        self.game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((self.display_width, 
        self.display_height))


    def gameLoop(self):

        while not self.game_exit:

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                    self.game_exit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

        self.game_display.fill(self.color_white)
        pygame.display.update()
        self.clock.tick(60)


game_instance = Bouncer()

game_instance.gameLoop()
```

> It gives me no error whatsoever

Comment: check your indenting. You never get out of your while loop to get to that piece of code.

Comment: @Reginol_Blindhop Oh yes I did I an issue with my indenting thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to draw the scene **in** the application loop rather than **after** the application loop:

```py
class Bouncer(object):
    # [...]

    def gameLoop(self):

        while not self.game_exit:

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                    self.game_exit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
   
        # INDENTATION

        #-->|

            self.game_display.fill(self.color_white)
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)
```